# SQL maior data de um registro antes da data determinada

Tags: sql, data

Seguinte tem o seguinte caso:

```
Tb_importacao [cod_titulo,data,imp_situacao]

cod_titulo   data_imp    situacao
1           2015-04-10      1
1           2015-04-11      2
1           2015-04-11      1
1           2015-04-13      2
1           2015-04-14      3
1           2015-04-14      4
```

Preciso da maior data que tenha situacao 1 `where data_imp < 2015-04-13`.
Minha tabela real possiu mais que um cod_titulos...

Vlw!

Comment: E qual é a dúvida?

Comment: `SELECT MAX(data_imp) FROM tb_importacao WHERE data_imp < '2015-04-13' AND situacao = 1` ?

Comment: + -  assim siatuação 1 = ativo, 2 = desativo

O cara fica indo e voltando na minha base
preciso da maior data de que ele estava ativo e a maior de inativo, para saber se na minha data alvo ele estava ativo ou nao.

Comment: Raphael, acabei de editar o sql, pode testar novamente?

Comment: Rafael:
assim eu so trago a maior data 
preciso disso por cod_titulo

Comment: É que você não forneceu todas as informações na pergunta... assim a gente vai indo no chute, pode editar ela e fornecer uma explicação detalhada do que você quer e talvez um exemplo do resultado final esperado?

Comment: data_alvo = 2015-04-13 situacao_alvo = 1

Resultado esperado

cod_titulo   data_imp    situacao

1           2015-04-11      1

Comment: Raphael, você pode editar sua pergunta no link (editar) logo abaixo dela, ou por aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/58826/edit

Comment: Tem como alguém ajudar nesta questão de datas? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120596/como-fazer-um-sql-que-consulte-apenas-o-dia-de-uma-data

Answer (score 4):

Indo por partes:

- Selecionar a maior *data_imp* => `MAX(data_Imp)`
- Quando a *data_imp* for menor que *2015-04-13*
  e a situação for *1* =>`WHERE data_imp < '2015-04-13' AND situacao = 1`
- Por cada *cod_titulo* => `GROUP BY cod_titulo`

Juntando tudo:

```
SELECT cod_titulo, MAX(data_imp) FROM tb_importacao 
WHERE data_imp < '2015-04-13' AND situacao = 1
GROUP BY cod_titulo
```

Comment: exemplo a data da situacao 1 saiu 2015-04-10
so que esse cod_titulo teve uma situacao 2 no dia 2015-04-11
entao no dia 13 que é o alvo no caso esse cara nao estava ativo eé isso que preciso

Comment: Não entendi. A *query* da minha resposta traz ou não o resultado que espera? Se não qual é o esperado?

Comment: Devolução 09/04/2015 16:19
Reingresso 09/04/2015 16:19
Importação 09/04/2015 16:19

no dia 9 esse cara nao tava ativo pois o ultimo registro devolve o cara

preciso saber se o cara tava ativo na data alvo

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia testar esse SQL? Ia deixar nos comentários mas é muito grande.
Talvez precise de alguma adaptação ainda para chegar ao resultado exato que você precisa.
Só avisar que vamos modelando ela. (Não tenho como testar)

```
SELECT imp1.cod_titulo, MAX(imp2.data_imp) as data_ativa, MAX(imp3.data_imp) as data_inativa FROM tb_importacao as imp1
JOIN tb_importacao as imp2 ON imp2.situacao = 1
JOIN tb_importacao as imp3 ON imp3.situacao = 2
WHERE imp1.data_imp < '2015-04-13'
GROUP BY cod_titulo
```

No caso ele vai retornar duas datas. A maior data ativa (data_ativa) e maior data inativa (data_inativa), então você compara com sua data alvo na programação.

Comment: Cara o problema é que a data_imp esta numa tabela e a situacao em outra D=

Comment: Ah... ai não ia conseguir adivinhar isso... A estrutura que você forneceu na pergunta não é a sua tabela então? Qual é essa tabela de situacao?

Comment: É que o treco ta complexo man
O sistema aqui eh uma merda

Tenho a IMPORTACAO que é onde tem a data de entrada do registro
Tenho a IMPORTACAO_HISTORICO que tem a situacao e o cod_titulo

Sua query estava seguindo o rumo certo so que nao te forneci os dados mesmo

obrigado

Comment: kkkk, testei aqui uma tabela com a estrutura que você forneceu na pergunta e aparentemente está funcionando esse SQL. Só precisamos adaptar a sua situação, você não pode fornecer mais detalhes? Ou você pega o sql ali em cima e edita para unir com sua tabela de situacao, ou essa situacao é uma foreign key na tabela tb_importacao?

Answer (score -1):

Tente utilizando a função GREATEST.

```
select greatest(col1, col2, col3, col4) from tab1;
```